# How to use a filename based on a build setting

Tags: bazel

I have a build setting like:

```
string_flag(
    name = "version",
    build_setting_default = "0.1")
```

I want to use it to create a file, e.g.:

```
ctx.actions.run_shell(
    outputs = ["report-%s.csv" % (version)],
    inputs = ctx.files.inputs,
    command = "$(location //build:report-generator.sh) 2>&1"
)
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Error in run_shell: at index 0 of outputs, got element of type string, want File
```

Here is the docs for File: https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/File.html

> created during the analysis phase

So my question is, how do you get the value of a build setting during the analysis phase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message says, the `outputs` argument to `run_shell` expects a list of `File` objects rather than strings. One generally obtains an appropriate output `File` object by [declaring an output in the rule class definition](https://bazel.build/rules/rules#files) or using the [`ctx.actions.declare_file`](https://bazel.build/rules/lib/actions#declare_file) method.